# Can't get Spring dependency Injection to work

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations

I'm pretty much a total beginner to Spring so don't assume that just because I didn't mention something I probably did it anyway.

I'm trying to get dependency injection to work, I got a spring.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.1.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<bean id="connection" class="richo.project.ConnectionImpl"/>
</beans>
```

and then in my code I have:

```
private IConnection conn;
@Resource(name="connection")
public void setConn(IConnection conn){
this.conn = conn;
}
```

and when I try to use the conn-object in my code I get a nullpointerexception

Bear in mind that I don't actually know if spring is running, I'm using IntelliJ and it placed 13 spring related jar-files in my lib directory, but I can't really tell if Spring is even trying to inject anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just having Spring in your classpath is not enough to make this work.

You *must* ask Spring to produce the object you need for any annotations to be honoured.  Either this happens in a Spring container, but for stand-alone applications you need to have a Spring context (e.g. AnnotationConfigApplicationContext) and ask it through its `getBean()` method.

Comment: So the annotations in a class only works if Spring instantiates it, meaning that If I simply use new <classname> spring will not read those annotations?

Comment: This is true for Guice.  I am not sure if it is the case for Spring (question of _how_ much classloader magic is in place).

Comment: @Richo: yes, Spring only injects beans that it creates. Beans that you instantiate yourself won't be injected.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by getting the ApplicationContext and getting the bean from there. Thanks

Comment: @Richo, just for the record.  If all you want is Dependency Injection on a stand-alone application, then I would suggest Guice.  Their configuration approach is much easier to get right the first time.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, thanks for the advice but we're using Spring at the company I work at so I want to learn how to use it

Answer (score 0):

First, your code doesn't compile. It should adhere to JavaBeans conventions, and the method should thus be

```
public void setConn(IConnection conn){
    this.conn = conn;
}
```

Now, just because you have a spring XML file and the spring jars in your classpath doesn't make Spring magically run and inject dependencies. You need to load an application context, and load at least one bean from this context. This bean will have all its dependencies injected, recursively.

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-instantiation for an example.

Comment: if you're referring to the "voidSetConn" then that was a typo which I've corrected in my question